# Android check if JSON response is null

Tags: android, json

In an Android App I need to check if a JSON response is null.
This is my code:

```
private void showJSON(String response) {
    String nombre = "";
    String direccion = "";
    String codigo = "";
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);
        JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(0);
        nombre = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_NAME);
        direccion = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_ADDRESS);
        codigo = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_VC);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (nombre.isEmpty()) {
        nombre = "AGENCIA NO ENCONTRADA";
        textViewResult.setText("Agencia:\t" + nombre);
    }
    else {

        textViewResult.setText("Agencia:\t" + nombre + "\nDireccion:\t" + direccion + "\nCodigo:\t" + codigo);
    }
}
```

I have tried with:

```
if (nombre.isEmpty()) {

if (nombre == null) {

if (nombre == "") {
```

But the app always shows the else part of the if condition.
And the output if there are no data from JSON is always:

Agencia: null
Direccion null
Codigo: null

If there are data, the output is the right output.
Any help is welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In android use TextUtils.isEmpty() to check null instead.
But I think in your case nombre is not null.
String nombre = "null"; likely in your case.

Comment: You are right, In my case nombre == "null" is right. Thank you,

Comment: Glad it helps! ;-)